# Strongloop: filter data with [and] and [or] conditions together

Tags: mysql, node.js, strongloop

I'm trying to filter data using "and" and "or" conditions.
I would like to get this mySql query:

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE ((`property1`=11) OR (`property1`=13)) AND (`property2`=6)
```

The rest api that I wrote is like this:

```
http://localhost:4000/api/Data/?filter[where][or][0][property1]=11&filter[where][or][1][property1]=13&filter[where][and][0][property2]=6
```

The loopback json translation seems to be correct:

```
{                                            
    "or": [                              
            {                            
                    "property1": 11      
            },                           
            {                            
                    "property1": 13      
            }                            
    ],                                   
    "and": [                             
            {                            
                    "property2": 6     
            }                            
    ]                                    
}
```

But the translated query on mySql is:

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE (`property1`=11) OR (`property1`=13) AND (`property2`=6)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You need to encapsulate `or` into `and`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct filter is like :

```
{     
    "and": [
        {                            
          "property2": 6     
        } ,
        {
        "or": [                              
            {                            
                    "property1": 11      
            },                           
            {                            
                    "property1": 13      
            }                            
    ]   }    
    ]                              
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ebrahim. The json structure is clear but I don't understand how to obtain this json from an api rest call.

Comment: @FrancescoDeRosa Maybe `filter[where][and][0][or][0][property1]=11&filter[where][and][0][or][1][property1]=13&filter[where][and][1][property2]=6`