# Filter 'or' and 'and' together in Loopback 4

Tags: rest, filter, strongloop, loopback

I am using loopback 4 and trying to use filter [and] and [or] together via rest api. I have a table like this

[image: Items]

what i want is to `show only items which has cond1 = 0 and cond2 = 0 and (cond3 = 1 or cond3 = 2 or cond3 = 3)`.

the json would be like this

```js
{
  "and": [
      {
        "cond1": 0
      },
      {
        "cond2": 0
      },
      {
        "or": [
          {
            "cond3":1
          },
          {
            "cond3":2
          },
          {
            "cond3":3
          }
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

this is my rest api filter

`filter[where][and][0][cond1]=0&filter[where][and][1][cond2]=0&filter[where][and][2][or][0][cond3]=1&&filter[where][and][2][or][1][cond3]=2&&filter[where][and][2][or][2][cond3]=3`

i've found similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38262282/strongloop-filter-data-with-and-and-or-conditions-together) and what i've done looks similar with [Ebrahim Pasbani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861885/ebrahim-pasbani) answers.

But instead of getting this result

[image: Items]

I'm getting this one

[image: Items]

which means the `[and][2][or][0]` syntax is miss understood by loopback as `[neq]`. I've tried to ask around but looks like anyone else had same problem with me and end up unsolved. i'd appreciate any answer and it possible with some explanation.

thanks before

Answer (score 0):

found the answer on loopback telegram groups.

aparently you can write json string at rest api (with symbol translation for sure). so the answer is :

```
filter={%22%where%22:{%22and%22:[{%22or%22:[{%22cond3%22:1}{%22cond3%22:2},{%22cond3%22:3}]}],%22cond1%22:0,%22cond2%22:0}}
```

note: %22 => " in url string.

and voilaa....
the result is exactly as i expected. Hope this could answer for anyone who hit the same issue.